# Someone stole money from my account, how can I get it back?

Tags: banking

Somebody sent in a check that was more than it was supposed to be, I returned the money they asked for back, and a week later they stole $950.00 from my account. is there any way to get my money back?? please

Answer (score 7):

You were the subject of a typical scam - you cashed a check that was drawn on a stolen account, and then you forwarded the money to a second account or via other means (Western Union etc).  The owner of the stolen account informed their bank and the check was reversed, returning the original money from your account, leaving you completely out of pocket.

If you forwarded the money by bank transfer or check, contact your bank and report the fraud.  If you forwarded the money via another means, such as Western Union, then these methods are usually non-reversible and you will remain out of pocket.

You will not be able to get the money back from the stolen account, that was their bank reversing a fraudulent check, they wont do anything to help you.

Talk to your bank.  Talk to the police.